# FileNotFoundException when calling setImageURI(): /data/user/0/com.myapp/files/1585300417998.jpg: open failed: ENOENT

Tags: android

With Android 10, when calling

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageURI(uri)
```

I see this silent exception in the logs:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.myapp/files/1585300417998.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:115)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1192)
        at android.graphics.ImageDecoder$ContentResolverSource.createImageDecoder(ImageDecoder.java:282)
        at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeDrawableImpl(ImageDecoder.java:1743)
        at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeDrawable(ImageDecoder.java:1736)
        at android.widget.ImageView.getDrawableFromUri(ImageView.java:1009)
        at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:978)
        at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageURI(AppCompatImageView.java:116)
        at com.myapp.LargeImageView.setImage(LargeImageView.java:88)
        at com.myapp.LargeImageView.onSizeChanged(LargeImageView.java:56)
```

These two permissions are declared in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Do you check if the file exists?

Comment: That path is for internal storage, so those permissions are not necessary. Most likely, as sebi0920 suggested, the file truly does not exist.

Comment: You are absolutely right, the file did not exist. My apologies. I'll delete this question, unless you want to post your comment as an answer